# How to give alternate color to row when row created dynamically?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am creating row dynamically in while loop.

As data fetched from specific directory, required row will created.
But i want to give alternate zebra color to row. fro that what i will have to do ?

Following code is on my jsp page :

```
<% 

        while(rsemail.next())
        {
             user_email = rsemail.getString(2);
             file_name = rsemail.getString(3);
             file_size = rsemail.getFloat(4);
             file_type = rsemail.getString(5);

             for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
                {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
                    {
                        if(listOfFiles[i].getName().equals(file_name))
                        {
                            row_counter = row_counter + 1;
                            %>

                                <tr height="28px"  id="table_row" bgcolor="#C6C6C6">
                                  <td width="7%"><div align="center"><%= id=id+1 %></div></td>
                                  <td width="39%"><%=listOfFiles[i].getName() %></td>
                                  <td width="12%"><%= file_type  %></td>
                                  <td width="14%"><%= file_size/1000 %> KB</td>
                                  <td width="14%"><div align="center">Delete</div></td>
                                  <td width="14%"><div align="center"><a href="Savefile?path=d:\Reports\&filename=<%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%>">Download</a> </div></td>
                                </tr>                             
                            <%
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        %>
```

table show directory data which can be downloaded as well as it's name & type & size also displaying.
show i want to put it up in some arranged alternate manner.

> **So anyone can help me ???**

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like this

```
<%
 String StrBgEven = "#C6C6C6", strBgOdd = "#FFFFFF"; // outside loop
 if( i%2 == 0 ){
%>
 <tr height="28px"  id="table_row" bgcolor="<%=strBgEven%>">
<%  
}else{
%>
 <tr height="28px"  id="table_row" bgcolor="<%=strBgOdd%>">
<%
} 
%>
```

Comment: @ Hardik Mishra , Thank u so much..  i have solved it. thanx for such a wonderful help..

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the two colors into an array `colors`.
2. Initialize an integer `i` to `0`.
3. In the loop body where you iterate over the rows of the table

   1. assign the color `colors[i]` to the current row
   2. update `i` to the value of `1-i`

To clarify this, the `i` in the above algorithm has to be renamed, because `i` is used your code already.

Comment: `1-i` is OK, because if `i == 1`, then `1-i == 0` and if `i == 0`, then `1-i == 1`. The update therefore toggles between `0` and `1`. Incrementing `i` and using `i%2` would also work and can easily be extended to an arbitrary number of colors. I don't know JSP, so no code from me.

Answer (score 0):

Use row count inside the loop and check `if(rowcount%2==0)` if, true then change the back ground color by using css.

Example :-

**Loop started**

```
<tr style="<%if(cnt%2==0){ %>background-color:#ffffff;<%}else{%>background-color:#F9F9F9;<%} %>">

</tr>
```

**Loop End**

In the above example `<tr></tr>` you can put your data (`<td></td>`).

Hope it will help you.